# Expressing half-open interval [a,b) as infinite intersection of open intervals. (Answer Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need to express the half open interval $[a,b)$ where, $(a<b)$ as the infinite intersection of open intervals.

My answer/attempt is

$$[a,b)=\bigcap\limits^\infty_{n=1}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$$ I'm not sure if this is correct however.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun thank you. I'll only ask one question. I'm not sure why I received two downvotes. I even provided my solution and was just wondering if it was correct.

Comment: It's probably because you asked two questions in one post.

Comment: @Shaun. So should I just edit the question and remove the entire bullet point 2. with the second question to remove the downvotes?

Comment: It's worth a shot.

Comment: What am I talking about? I mean yes.

Comment: @Shaun I removed the second question.

Comment: Good. Also, notice how I edited your attempt. I placed the dollar signs either side of the entire thing, rather than each entry.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun. So if I want to ask the second question should I create a new post?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prove that $L=[a,b) =\displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a-\frac{1}{n},b\right)=R$, you need to show that one is the subset of the other. To show $L \subseteq R$, we start with some $x \in [a,b)$. Then $a-\frac{1}{n}<a\leq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x \in R$.

Now we start with $y \in R$, this means for all $n \geq 1$, we have $a-\frac{1}{n}<y<b$.

If $y \not\in L$, that would mean $y<a$. So let $y=a-\epsilon$, with $\epsilon >0$, by the Archimedean property, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\epsilon >1$. This would mean, 
$$y=a-\epsilon <a-\frac{1}{k}.$$
But then $y \not\in \left(a-\frac{1}{k},b\right)$. This contradicts the assumption we made at the very beginning. So $y \in L$.

Similarly you can check the other part.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is correct if your intervals make sense. 
For instance $(a+1/n,b) $ makes sense if $a+1/n<b$

I would change the $1/n$ to $(b-a)/n$ to take care of that.